# How to make the view the same for all platforms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

When I try to make a listview with a custom layout it looks completely different on UWP than Android. How can I make them look the same on all platforms without making a Page per platform?
I try to let my app looks like the wireframe.

I try to visualize an object as a viewcell with a background image and two labels.

I'm currently developing an app for Android and UWP using Xamarin with **.NET standard** as code sharing strategy.

The idea of this project is to make every view/business logic in the shared project, (the upper project file) since the app won't use any platform specific features.

Here is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="inleiding.Views.SubList"
             Title="Your pokélist"
              NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="go back"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             >
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Text="Cars" FontSize="Large" TextColor="LightGray" />

        <ListView x:Name="lvwPok" ItemSelected="lvwPok_ItemSelected">


            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>

                            <RelativeLayout>
                                <Image  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Source = "{Binding Pic}"></Image>


                                <Grid
                                     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                    >
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" Source = "{Binding ImgPok}">
                                    </Image>
                                    <Label  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Spec}"  />
                                    <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{ Binding Type }"  />
                                </Grid>

                            </RelativeLayout>


                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

([Pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/bgUW3EF0))

[image: This is what I try to become]

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add `OnPlatform` support in your *Xaml*

> Within the tags, include an `OnPlatform` tag.
>
> `OnPlatform` is a generic class. You need to specify the generic type
>   argument, in the below exmaple Thickness, which is the type of Padding
>   property. Fortunately, there’s a XAML attribute specifically to define
>   generic arguments called x:TypeArguments. This should match the type
>   of the property you're setting:

**Exmaple**

```
<StackLayout.Padding>
  <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
    <On Platform="Android" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <On Platform="WinPhone" Value="0, 0, 0, 0"/>
    <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0"/>
  </OnPlatform>
</StackLayout.Padding>
```

Additional Resources

[Part 2. Essential XAML Syntax - Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/essential_xaml_syntax/)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not in the xaml but in image scaling. Android and UWP handle image scaling very differently, if you want a uniform look you need to provide correctly scaled images to UWP and provide Android with the correponding sizes.

Take a look here: [UWP, how to handle images and scaling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258767/uwp-how-to-handle-images-and-scaling)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have multiple questions in one.

The cut off in android: try setting HasUnevenRows to true (a property on the listview)

For the rounded corner you have to go for a [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), which leads to you having to create rounded borders the native elements representing the gras.
It's a Xamarin.Forms.Image right? So for android, you would have to use the ImageRenderer or the (AppCompat.)ViewRenderer.

I could only give you a more elaborate example for android for rounded corners, if you can't find help for this on the net.